# Github workflow doesn't execute

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow

I created a.yml github workflow that has to execute when I create a pull request but I don't know why it doesn't execute.

What I am trying to do is:

- Get the branch name
- With the last part of the branch name for example `test` from `feature/hosting/test` assign it to the deploy channel in firebase
- after the deploy install `jq`
- Get the hosting utl generated in the deploy
- With the url, add a comment in the pull request with the url information

This is my .yml

```yaml
name: Firebase Test Deploy

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - bugfix/hosting/*
      - feature/hosting/*

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '14'
      - name: Install Firebase CLI
        run: npm install -g firebase-tools
      - name: Get branch name
        id: get_branch_name
        run: echo "::set-output name=branch::$(echo $GITHUB_REF | cut -d/ -f2-)"
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        run: |
          cd functions && firebase use --token $FIREBASE_TOKEN
          firebase hosting:channel:deploy ${{ steps.get_branch_name.outputs.branch }} --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
      - name: Install jq
        run: sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get install -y jq
      - name: Get Hosting URL
        id: get_hosting_url
        run: |
          hosting_url=$(firebase hosting:channel:list --json | jq -r '.[0].url')
          echo "::set-output name=hosting_url::$hosting_url"
        shell: bash
      - name: Comment on Pull Request
        uses: actions/github-script@0.12.0
        with:
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const { context, github } = require('@actions/github');
            
            const comment = `
              **Firebase Hosting URL:**
              ${steps.get_hosting_url.outputs.hosting_url}
            `;
            
            github.issues.createComment({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              body: comment,
            })
```

The route of the .yml file is `.github/workflows`.

Where is the error?

Comment: What are the branches for which this workflow isn't triggered?

Comment: Right now I have a branch named feature/hosting/disable-credit-card and it doesn't trigger. Actually in this branch I created the .yml file

Comment: I think the `pull_request.branches` changes has to be in the default branch. If you want to test within `feature/hosting/disable-credit-card`, can you remove the `pull_request.branches` option and check if its triggered within your branch?

Comment: It works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `.yml` workflow file is created within the same branch (`feature/hosting/disable-credit-card`) for which you wish to trigger the workflow, and if that workflow file has not been merged into the base branch, the workflow will not be triggered for the pull request. GitHub Actions will only recognize workflow files that are in the base branch of the pull request. That is likely the issue you are facing.

Add the workflow file directly to the base branch you are targeting (often `main` or `master`).
Once the workflow file is present in the base branch, the workflow should trigger for future pull requests matching the conditions you have set.